# Current location Iframe when change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function enviar(parametro){
var conteudo = $('#iframe_conteudo').attr('src');
alert(conteudo);
}
</script>
<a href="#" id="" onclick="enviar('pegar')">pick url</a>
<iframe id="iframe_conteudo" src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

When I change the link inside the iframe, for example:

Yahoo.com is running inside the iframe, when i click on the 'games' in yahoo website, the iframe reload me to the new page (inside the iframe), but when I click on the button 'pick url', instead of grabbing the url where I am exactly, it returns me a alert. to the first url that is the 'yahoo.com' Why is this happening?'

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$("#iframe_conteudo").get(0).contentWindow.location
```

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "http://br.yahoo.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Answer (score 0):

*Why is this happening?*

Its because your iframe's url has not been changed when page in the iframe navigated to new page address. You have navigated to different page but you have not changed the src of the iframe. That is why it will always alerts the original src applied to the iframe.

you can debug it with firebug/chromeInspector.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is checking the "src" attribute, which is hardcoded to "http://www.yahoo.com". The "src" attribute doesn't change when you load a new url in the iframe.

Try: $("#iframe_conteudo").contentDocument.location

This will only work if both are within the same domain. By default, the same-origin policy will prevent cross domain.